# Python function for taking formatted input from user similar to scanf() in 'C'

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a function in Python to take *formatted* input from user similar to taking the input from user in 'C' using `scanf()` and format strings such as `%d`, `%lf`, etc.

Hypothetical example in which `scanf()` returns a `list`:

```py
input_date_list = scanf("%d-%d-%d")
# User enters "1969-04-20"
input_time_list = scanf("%d:%d")
# User enters "04:20"
print(input_date_list, input_time_list)
# Output is "[1969, 4, 20] [4, 20]"
```

Comment: `input()` in Python 3, `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Comment: This has to be explained in most tutorials.

Comment: a tutorial: http://python3porting.com/differences.html#input-and-raw-input

Comment: dont ask me the que dude...

Comment: OP should probably delete this question, which will regain rep.

Comment: This is not a duplicate IMO, scanf is a very specific tool and I don't think `raw_input` will cover all of its functionalities

Comment: I agree with @radrow, in python you can't read in a formatted style, like `scanf("%d %f", &my_int, &my_float)`. In python after reading with input() you should parse every entry in the input to typecast and assign variables.

Comment: @Barmar `input()` or `raw_input()` is similar to `gets` but OP is asking for `scanf`.

Comment: @tsh The question is so vague it's hard to tell what they're really asking for.

Comment: @Barmar I think it is clear enough. Python have a string format operator `'%d, %d' % (3, 4) ` which works just like what `printf` (or say, `sprintf`) do. So it could be easy to Python beginners with C background to ask "if there are something similar to `scanf`". Should OP include what `scanf` do (maybe copy [what `man` says](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)) in the post so it become clear?

Answer (score 5):

## What the Standard Library provides

There is no direct scanf(3) equivalent in the standard library. The documentation for the `re` module suggests itself as a replacement, providing [this explanation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html?highlight=scanf#simulating-scanf):

> Python does not currently have an equivalent to scanf(). Regular expressions are generally more powerful, though also more verbose, than scanf() format strings. The table below offers some more-or-less equivalent mappings between scanf() format tokens and regular expressions.

Modifying your hypothetical example, to work with regular expressions, we get...

```py
import re

input_date_list = re.match(r"(?P<month>[-+]?\d+)-(?P<day>[-+]?\d+)-(?P<year>[-+]?\d+)", input())
print(f"[{input_date_list['year']}, {input_date_list['month']}, {input_date_list['day']}]")

input_time_list = re.match(r"(?P<hour>[-+]?\d+):(?P<minute>[-+]?\d+)", input())
print(f"[{input_time_list['hour']}, {input_time_list['minute']}]")
```

...and when executed:

```bash
python script.py << EOF
1-2-2023
11:59
EOF
[2023, 1, 2]
[11, 59]
```

## Community Implementation

The [scanf module](https://pypi.org/project/scanf/) on Pypi provides an interface much more akin to scanf(3).

This provides a direct implementation of your hypothetical examples:

```py
from scanf import scanf

input_date_list = scanf("%d-%d-%d")
input_time_list = scanf("%d:%d")

print(input_date_list, input_time_list)
```

...and when executed:

```bash
python script.py << EOF
1-2-2023
11:59
EOF
(1, 2, 2023) (11, 59)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no (built-in) direct and easy way to specify the input's format in Python.

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function in Python 3 ([`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) in Python 2) will simply return the string that was typed to STDIN. Any parsing will be done manually on the string.

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) function in Python ***2*** (`eval(input())` in Python 3, [which is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)) did a very basic built-in parsing and would work for only a single element (i.e. equivalent to `scanf("%d")` for instance).

With some basic parsing you can get to not-so-complicated code that emulates `scanf`:

```
# scanf("%d-%d-%d")
input_date_list = [int(x) for x in input().split('-')]

# scanf("%d:%d")
input_time_list = [int(x) for x in input().split(':')]
```

For anything more complicated, more lines of code are needed. For example:

```
# scanf("%d,%f - %s")
nums, s = input().split(' - ')
i, f = nums.split(',')
i = int(i)
f = float(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()`. For example this could be used as:

```
Name = input("Please enter your name?")
```

For use in Python 2, this would be `raw_input()`. For example this could be used as:

```
Name = raw_input("Please enter your name?")
```

Comment: This does not explain how to get *formatted* input from the user. This would be closer to `fgets()` or (I hate to say it) `gets()`.

Answer (score -2):

in Python 2, you can use `input()` or `raw_input()`

```
s = input()     // gets int value        

k = raw_input()   // gets string value
```